# How to share content/data through other apps in an iOS app like we do in an Android app with Intent.ACTION_SEND?

Tags: android, ios, android-intent, share, send

In Android, we can easily share content (text, images, video etc) through the Intent.ACTION_SEND startactivity api.

I have an app doing that perfectly already, and have a parallel iOS app that I hope to implement the same feature.

Is there any iOS api support or do I have to use 3rd party sdks or code my own interface layer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

You can do that by implementing a [custom URL scheme](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html). Also check this [blog](http://kotikan.com/blog/item/passing-data-between-ios-apps) out.

This [long question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801590/ios-app-to-app-trasnmission-of-data-using-new-document-support-api)  approaches the techniques for transmitting information as documents. Be aware that due to the sandboxing, "moving" huge piles of data around (from one application to another) will not be *straightforward* and you will have to slightly rethink your interaction process.

[Several](http://handleopenurl.com/scheme) [sites](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes) *attempt* to list the schemes, but unless Apple decides to publish them, they're bound to be inaccurate.

Comment: Thanks Kheldar, checking out the links you posted! :)

Wonder if the iOS system can return a list of apps or custom URL schemes?

PS: I'm new here ... so cannot even upvote your reply! *gasp*

Comment: Last time I checked, it could not. At a time, when you tried to register a scheme already used, you got an exception. There are several sites trying to list all used URL schemes but none is complete to my knowledge. Don't worry about upvoting, as long as you solve your issue :D

Answer (score 0):

Use UIActivityViewController for sharing content with social networking apps.