# iOS only, share image from gallery to my Ionic/Cordova/Phonegap application

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap

I am trying to share image from gallery and want to get it in my ionic application. I have tried a lot but still not understanding this.

I have tried following plugins:

https://github.com/protonet/cordova-plugin-share-extension-helper

https://github.com/markmarijnissen/cordova-plugin-share

[How to share content/data through other apps in an iOS app like we do in an Android app with Intent.ACTION_SEND?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294221/how-to-share-content-data-through-other-apps-in-an-ios-app-like-we-do-in-an-andr)

http://www.technetexperts.com/mobile/share-extension-in-ios-application-overview-with-example/

https://github.com/LokeshPatel/iOS-Phonegap-app-share-extension

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559991/cordova-register-file-types-to-open-with-list?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @BhavanPatel unfortunately what you are looking forward is not straight forward in iOS. Check out my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712312/make-ionic-app-appear-in-share-list-and-receive-data/43867316#43867316 Hope it helps. Let me know your comments so that i can add the answer here too.

Comment: @BhavanPatel Any update on this?

Comment: @Gandhi Not yet trying to achieve it.

Comment: @BhavanPatel Could you accept the answer so that it will be helpful for others too and bounty seems to be running out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some detailed analysis, this is what I could conclude:

In Android, you could just get your application added in the share list using cordova-plugin-intent as described [in this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42384763/sharing-photo-photos-to-my-ionic-2-application-from-share-button-in-gallery-im). You can also achieve this by adding intent filter in the activity as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350857/how-do-i-add-my-app-to-the-android-share-photo-option)

In iOS, this is bit tricky as there are no straight forward plugins or readymade solution available to achieve this. But the best possible link i could get related to adding app in iOS share menu is [getting listed in share menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107446/how-to-get-listed-in-the-share-menu) The link includes apple documentation to do this and also some tweaking in Info.plist to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this plugin https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker 
The usage has been described there. It gives you the path of the image.

You can use that path or read the imagefile to get `base64` equivalent of it. e.g.

```
window.imagePicker.getPictures(
function(results) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createImage(results[i])
    }
}, function (error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + error);
})

createImage(fileURL){
  var img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
  img.src = fileURL;      
  img.onload = function(){
      // processing
}}
```

Comment: I don't want image picker. I want like my app shows in gallery [in share extension] and on click of that  share extension , I want to get that image in my application.

Comment: @BhavanPatel This also opens the gallery and allow you to choose images. I have used this plugin and displayed the images in my ionic application. Is your use case different?

Comment: My case is different If I want image from gallery I have already used picker one but I want to share image to my application. As whatsapp has dual functionality like  also attach from  app and also share from gallery to application... I have already implemented pick from application but I also need to share image from gallery to my application.

Comment: @BhavanPatel hope this can help https://blog.bam.tech/developper-news/building-a-picture-gallery-with-cordova